# run demo django app on google app engine (DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.)

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am trying to run the django 1.3 test app named Polls in googleappenginelauncher version 1.6.6 and am getting the following error. Can anyone tell me how to do this, please?

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
INFO     2012-06-05 19:08:30,766 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET /polls/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I have placed my app.yaml in the app directory, not the project directory, and that may be a problem, but here is my current app.yaml. Also, I have declared my views.py as my main script, which was also a guess.

```
application: ctst
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: views.app

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
```

My mysite and my polls directories are as follows.

```
server:mysite brian$ ls -l
total 352
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff       0 Jun  4 10:22 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff     155 Jun  4 13:56 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff     503 Jun  4 10:22 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x  20 brian  staff     680 Jun  5 14:54 polls
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff    5273 Jun  5 15:00 settings.py
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff    2955 Jun  5 15:00 settings.pyc
drwxr-xr-x   2 brian  staff      68 Jun  4 14:04 sqlite3.db
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff  147456 Jun  5 11:42 sqlite3.dp
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff    1048 Jun  5 10:16 urls.py
-rw-r--r--   1 brian  staff     464 Jun  5 10:18 urls.pyc
server:mysite brian$ ls -l polls/
total 104
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff     0 Jun  4 14:23 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   151 Jun  4 14:33 __init__.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   505 Jun  4 16:33 admin.py
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff  1123 Jun  4 16:33 admin.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   263 Jun  5 14:54 app.yaml
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   524 Jun  4 14:50 models.py
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff  1484 Jun  4 14:50 models.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   383 Jun  4 14:23 tests.py
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   708 Jun  5 11:26 urls.py
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff   902 Jun  5 11:42 urls.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff  1154 Jun  5 11:41 views.py
-rw-r--r--  1 brian  staff  1231 Jun  5 11:42 views.pyc
server:mysite brian$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

somewhere you know it's called for every request. Note that os.environ is threadlocal with python27, so setting on initial import is probably not enough.

Comment: Where do you add these things (in views.py, e.g.)? I've already got that in settings.py .

Comment: Try in views.py (see what works), or always import settings before you use anything Django.

Comment: Notice that settings.py is not in the polls directory where the app files are. And also that the os.environ[...] says 'settings', not 'settings.py' or '../settings', or ... . Could that be a problem?

Comment: The django code seems to do importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) which indicates it should be python.path.to.module (neither / nor .py in there) You could mangle sys.path beforehand to make the import work.

Comment: I have made a discovery: that the handlers must be taken from the djangoappengine which "Sepero" so kindly made it easy to install. And all of those djangoappengine files must be in the same directory as "my site" and the url handler which handles /.* must be main from the django code, not my code, as you can see below.

Comment: handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: djangoappengine.deferred.handler.application
  login: admin
- url: /_ah/stats/.*
  script: djangoappengine.appstats.application

- url: /media/admin
  static_dir: django/contrib/admin/media
  expiration: '0'

- url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine.main.application

Comment: I am totally frustrated with django because I continue to get errors  that I don't understand like the following one (because index.html and poll_list.html must be django files, not mine) 
TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/index.html, polls/poll_list.html
INFO     2012-06-08 17:35:40,114 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: I don't have any particular experience with djangoappengine. Maybe it makes sense to either update the original question or create a new one as you come across new issues?

Comment: Someone on the semimonthly google apps chat suggested that I forget about django and instead look into jinja2 which is more like early django, and is not a monolithic as django 1.3. So I am now studying jinja2 and have given up on django, or at least suspended my interest. Thanks.